# How to setup wildcard domain ssl with letsencrypt greenlock?

Tags: node.js, lets-encrypt, greenlock

I am pretty much new to setting up ssl server i am just exploring a package called greelock

https://www.npmjs.com/package/greenlock

trust me i am using real domain for this setting up ssl.

after installed all packages i run this code.

```
'use strict';

require('greenlock-express').create({

  // Let's Encrypt v2 is ACME draft 11
  version: 'draft-11'

  // Note: If at first you don't succeed, switch to staging to debug
  // https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
        // https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
, server: 'https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory'

  // Where the certs will be saved, MUST have write access
, configDir: '~/.config/acme/'

  // You MUST change this to a valid email address
, email: 'somename@gmail.com'

  // You MUST change these to valid domains
  // NOTE: all domains will validated and listed on the certificate
, approveDomains: [ 'awesomedomain.com','*.awesomedomain.com' ]

  // You MUST NOT build clients that accept the ToS without asking the user
, agreeTos: true

, app: require('express')().use('/', function (req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8')
    res.end('Hello, World!\n\n   .js');
  })

  // Join the community to get notified of important updates
, communityMember: true

  // Contribute telemetry data to the project
, telemetry: true

//, debug: true

}).listen(80, 443);
```

Above code is working properly for base domain which is awesomedomain.com but when i try to visit some random subdomain i am facing this error

```
 [Error] approveDomains rejected tls sni 'david.awesomedomain.com'
    [Error] (see https://git.coolaj86.com/coolaj86/greenlock.js/issues/11)
```

Comment: Hey, sorry for the inconvenience. In the latest security updates I forgot to match wildcard domains. If you could just use multiple domains for now I’ll try to fix that in the next release.

Comment: Also, you’ll have to use the dns-01 challenge instead of the default http-01 challenge. Who do you use for DNS? Check the list of plugins at http://git.coolaj86.com/coolaj86/greenlock-express.js

Comment: @CoolAJ86 I am using cloudflare as my dns and yes i properly configured my wildcard settings in cloudflare

Comment: Since I only need wildcard domains for my application ill wait for your next release and  your package is awesome and simple to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use Greenlock v2.7+

Before Greenlock v2.7 there were a number of things you had to do manually to get wildcard registration to work.

I wrote a new file storage plugin so that it won't get tripped up with filesystems that don't allow `*`.

I also made it be a little smarter about using `dns-01` as required and `http-01` when allowable.

See the example at https://git.coolaj86.com/coolaj86/greenlock-express.js/src/branch/master/examples/wildcard.js

## DNS-01 Plugin

You'll still need a dns-01 plugin. Hit me up on issues if you try one of the ones listed in plugin section of the README and it's not working:

https://git.coolaj86.com/coolaj86/greenlock-express.js

Some of them are pretty old and although I've tried to maintain backwards compatibility through much pain, it's possible that something is amiss.

Comment: Coolaj86, the link to the wildcard example seems to be broken now. Is there a new place to find it? It's not in the examples folder in git right now. Also, thanks a bunch for greenlock!

Comment: @ChristianFritz that's the right link. Must have just been a network fluke.

Comment: hm, it still gives me a 404 (https://git.coolaj86.com/coolaj86/greenlock-express.js/src/branch/master/examples/wildcard.js).

Comment: @coolaj86 can confirm, that link does not work == 404.